# how to properly deal with bigdecimal values in ormlite?

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite, bigdecimal

Is it possible to use `sum()` function for bigdecimal column in **sqlite**, since they are stored as `varchar`? I'm using **ormlite** for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the "bigdecimal" is stored as string (SQLite3 TEXT type), then you cannot use the sum() function.  You have to either (1) extract the fields, convert them to some numeric type, and perform the sum() in your program, or (2) create a custom function in SQLite3 that would do the same, and call that.